# Why does the __proto__ object evaluate to "Object" in the debugger?

Tags: javascript, debugging, prototype, google-chrome-devtools, prototypal-inheritance

I'm reading Kyle Simpson's "YDKJS: this & Object Prototypes", and looking at his example of behavior delegation. Here's the code below:

```
Foo = {
    init: function(who) {
        this.me = who;
    },
    identify: function() {
        return "I am " + this.me;
    }
};

Bar = Object.create( Foo );

Bar.speak = function() {
    alert( "Hello, " + this.identify() + "." );
};

var b1 = Object.create( Bar );
b1.init( "b1" );
var b2 = Object.create( Bar );
b2.init( "b2" );

b1.speak();
b2.speak();
```

He uses this diagram to describe the relationships between these objects:

[image]

Now my question:

When tinkering with this code in Chrome Developer tools, I see that the `__proto__` object evaluates to `Object`. Why is that? Shouldn't the `__proto__` object depict the actual relationship in the diagram, where `b1` and `b2` delegate to `Bar` which in-turn delegates to `Foo`? Why are these relationships not explicitly named in the `__proto__` object? After-all, this implementation uses the `Object.create()` method, and places an argument in the `proto` parameter (the first parameter). Wouldn't it be expected that the console would return that named argument as the value of the `__proto__` object?

[image]

Comment: The `__proto__` is displayed as `Object` - but so are `Foo` and `Bar`. What would you expect it to display as? There are good reasons not to display it as `Foo` - objects don't know what names refer to them.

Comment: @user2357112 why wouldn't you expect it to contain a reference to the object it links to?

Comment: how do you get all of that in chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't quite so simple.  The `__proto__` property *is* a dynamic link to the `.constructor`'s prototype.

However, `.constructor` isn't overwritten in these cases (though it can be in certain hand-made libraries).

When you're looking for a reference to `Foo` to show up in that chain, it's a very "classical" viewpoint, and less to do with prototypal inheritance, which inherits from a concrete instance, rather than a class, and in the case of JS, references (when not scalar), rather than copies.

The tl;dr reason is simply: `Object.create`'s constructor is `Object`, `{}`'s constructor is `Object` and `Object.prototype`'s constructor is `Object`.

---

## The Long Way

First thing to know:
names in these lookups aren't tied to variables, but rather they're tied to functions, typically.
Once upon a time, the field where this information could be found was hidden, and now it's found it's way to the `.name` property of a function (`function Foo () { } Foo.name; //Foo`) in many browsers now (much like `__proto__` used to be invisible.

Second bit:
names which you see in console references, and in type-checks, aren't based on the **proto**, but on a property called `.constructor`.

```
// Equivalent assignments
var obj1 = { };
var obj2 = new Object();
var obj3 = Object.create(Object.prototype);

obj1.constructor; // Object
obj2.constructor; // Object
obj3.constructor; // Object
```

If we were to change the dynamic a little, and introduce the more "classical" approach to instance-creation, which is paseé, but will see a resurgence in ES6 with the `class` sugar...

```
function Foo () {
  this.isFoo = true;
}

var foo = new Foo();
foo.isFoo; // true
foo.constructor; // Foo
foo.__proto__ === Foo.prototype; // true
foo.__proto__.constructor; // Object
```

That last little bit there is telling, for your immediate question; `Foo.prototype` is nothing but a plain ol' `Object` instance.
In the days of JS where everybody was looking for the best possible way of making JS feel like Java / C#, you'd see something like:

```
function Foo () { }

function Bar() { }

Bar.prototype = new Foo();

var foo = new Foo();
var bar = new Bar();
bar instanceof Bar; // true
bar instanceof Foo; // true
```

On one hand, this sort of works, as we've been able to reuse method's of Foo on instances of Bar.
Grand.
The immediate downside is that all instances of `Bar` share the same instance of `Foo`, including all of its instance-specific properties.

While this method is far from what I'd suggest as a pattern for reuse, it does show off your dilemma well.

```
 // using the last set of assignments
 bar instanceof Foo;
 // equivalent to:
 bar.constructor === Foo; // false
 bar.__proto__.constructor === Foo; // true
 // not equivalent to
 bar.__proto__ == Foo;
```

More modern forms of "classical" inheritance (calling a `super` constructor, copying prototypes of other constructors onto your new constructor, etc) do a better job of allowing you to compose and reuse methods...

But that comes at the cost of being able to rely on the `__proto__` chain for looking up where those loaned methods come from.

Historically, the "bad for reuse, good for type-checking" model let you search
 `val.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__. (...) .__proto__.constructor`
until it matched your `instanceof`, or until you hit `Object` at the end of the line.

Newer forms copy the values directly onto `val.__proto__` (/ `val.constructor.prototype`, which we've seen is the same object, at creation of `val`), which means your proto chain runs out very quickly.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this clear and thorough response! I feel like I owe you something. LOL!